# Steps to implement node js with another programming language 

Tags: sockets, node.js, network-programming, udp

I want a Node JS server to communicate with a UDP or TCP client.

My questions:

1. What are the steps or suggestion when i want to create socket client with another language , but the server is using nodejs?
2. I have created UDP client with java, but when i want to connect to the Node JS server, i couldn't connect.  I think in node js any something rule to connect to server, how your opinion?

Comment: I'm not sure you're asking a question here. Any language, such as Java, is going to have a sockets API that talks to Node.js's.  You might want to include some Node and/or Java scource and explain what isn't working.

Comment: actually it is simmple i just wanna to connect my client program (java,C#,C,C++) UDP to Nodejs server, but i'm still error while try to implement that, maybe i have error in my program.so if any rule in nodejs when conect or in event emitter i can't solve that.when i try with my server program not using nodejs is run, but i think nodejs is powerfull

Comment: You need to add example code for the languages you used if you have a specific question. You can do exactly as you say with any of those languages. If you are doing this from a client rather than behind a firewall I would suggest REST or similar over raw TCP or UDP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP and UDP sockets are not language-dependant, if you have an UDP server in NodeJS, and an UDP Client in Java, this should work out of the box.

So you must be doing something wrong in your NodeJS or Java program. Here's a simple Hello world program :

Server.js :

```
var dgram = require("dgram");
var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

server.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {
  console.log("server got: " + msg + " from " +
    rinfo.address + ":" + rinfo.port);
});

server.on("listening", function () {
  var address = server.address();
  console.log("server listening " +
      address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

server.bind(41234);
// server listening 0.0.0.0:41234
```

and UDPClient.java :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPClient 
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
      DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
      InetAddress IPAddress =  InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
      byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
      String sentence = "Hello World!";
      sendData = sentence.getBytes();
      DatagramPacket sendPacket =  new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 41234);
      clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
      clientSocket.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: you right man maybe i will update your sample code but that is can make me solve my problem,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

> i'm sory if my question is bad, i mean i want to implement socket with
>   nodejs like UDP and TCP , i want to create socket client using another
>   programing.

You have to [choose between UDP or TCP.](http://smblog.iiitd.com/2010/09/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-tcp-and.html) Each protocol has it's advantages/disadvantages. I really like the two images on that site.

### **TCP**

[image: advantages TCP]

### **UDP**

[image]

I would suggest you to use TCP, especially when you don't have a lot experience implementing UDP. Furthermore I would suggest you to use HTTP(on top of TCP) because that is also wildly available in any programming language. I think a pretty easy solution would be to define a REST API. You can easily create server-side using [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) on the node side and [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) as the client-side(interact with other server implementation). On java you can for example use [atmosphere-spade-server](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) and [async-http-client](https://github.com/jfarcand/async-http-client)

> what are the steps or suggestion when i want to create socket client
>   with another language , but the server is using nodejs?

I suggest using [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) for data interchange. You can find a solid implementation in any language easily and the users browsers also has support for it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion actually i have implement TCP using nodejs + express + socket.io + mongoose, and that is successfull in my experiment, so i think the next i must be study using UDP because i think i will make a big game with multiply client, and when i'm read your suggesting UDP is better than TCP because that has be advantage in speed.

Comment: most games use TCP. UDP is more used for video, skype, etc where it is not a huge problem when you lose some data. I think for your game it will be bad...

Comment: why the UDP is bad for game? actually i'm confuse between this protocoll TCP or UDP is the best for game? can you explain me of details for different between TCP and UDP, i think can help me a lot.

Comment: UDP is very barebones. It does not provide you anything. TCP on the otherhand is very complete protocol. It supports ack(acknowledgments for data) => reliable transmission

Comment: thanks for your answer really help me a lot, i think i will use TCP like your suggestion, maybe in my game much data is important to request and response.

Comment: and using UDP for just not important data...:)

Answer (score 0):

There shouldnt be any problem in connecting two different programs over TCP or UDP. and in fact one of the basic purpose is to address such scenarios.

Try to write your node js server with spec in [here](http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html). it should work. If still it doesnt then post your java code as well. We can dig it thru.

Comment: thanks for suggesting that is the problem when i want to implement in event emitter nodejs using UDP/Datagram socket, i'm confuse how to implement event on message, on listener, on close , on error,  because in my client program not have that event emitter...